# How to load plugin only in IE10+

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery-resizable plugin:
https://github.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable. Loading it as in code below.

In IE10 I want to ignore it. How do I only load the plugin in IE11+ and other normal browsers? MS doesn't support conditional comments anymore... It can be a JS or JQ solution.

```
$(".mu-panel-left").resizable({
        handleSelector: ".mu-splitter",
        resizeHeight: false
    });

    $(".mu-panel-top").resizable({
        handleSelector: ".mu-splitter-horizontal",
        resizeWidth: false
    });
```

EDIT:
Would it then be better to add CSS like:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
     /* IE10+ only: assign X to body */
}
```

, then check with JQ if body has class X, and if it does then it's IE10+ ?

Comment: maybe you could try it with feature detection. try modernizr for this: https://modernizr.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution that should not be vulnerable to spoofing.

**CSS**

```
#x {margin-bottom:0;}

/* IE 10+ only */
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    #x {margin-bottom:1px;}
}
```

**JQ**

```
   var marg = parseInt( $('#x').css("marginBottom") );
   if (marg == 0) { alert ('not ie');}
   else {alert('ie 10');}
   // then do whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will check if the navigator is IE10 or not if the navigator is IE10 var is_ie10 == true otherwise is false
so you can check the is_ie10 if it contain false you can execute the function

```
function getIEVersion(){
    var agent = navigator.userAgent;
    var reg = /MSIE\s?(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?/i;
    var matches = agent.match(reg);
    if (matches != null) {
        return { major: matches[1], minor: matches[2] };
    }
    return { major: "-1", minor: "-1" };
}

var ie_version =  getIEVersion();
var is_ie10 = ie_version.major == 10;
```

PS we use navigator.userAgent to determine the platform, it is vulnerable to spoofing by the user or misrepresentation by the browser itself. It is always best to avoid browser-specific code entirely where possible.

For more information check [this](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/)

Comment: Would it be better then to use a CSS workaround I added?

Comment: it's impossible to add a html class using css; so you have to deal with it using javascript

Comment: I think I have another solution, see below: